# How can I get rid of this icon in my menu bar?

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar

I have this icon (which I never use) in my menu bar:

[image: screenshot]

What is this icon for and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: If you click on it, you probably get a menu that tells you what it belongs to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the position, it seems to be an app from Apple.

Press <kbd>Command</kbd> and drag & drop it out of the menu bar.

Comment: I didn't knew about this, it's awesome!

Comment: This works only for Mac OS features. Icons by third party vendors don't support this.

Comment: True. Some might, but they would be using private API. All the others (and probably all from the Mac App Store) can't.

Comment: That's not true. Spotlight is an OS X feature and you cannot move it, while iStat Menu is third party and you can drag it. Additionally the position in the menubar does not have anything to do with the feature being stock.

Comment: @bot47 Like I said, apps that use private APIs can act as if they are stock apps (that can be drag & dropped and can be placed wherever they want). iStat is probably the most famous of those apps. There's a downside to it, Apple can change those APIs whenever they want, so you can't be sure it'll always work. Spotlight is not a menu icon like the wifi or sound one, so it's normal it's not behaving the same way.