# What's the menu area near the clock called?

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar

[image: time machine, bluetooth, wifi, volume, battery, clock]

What is the part of the menu bar called with the time machine, bluetooth, wifi, volume and battery icons called? (Near the clock)

I wanted to search how to remove unused icons from it (like timemachine)

---

Edit: [How can I get rid of this icon in my menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27342/how-can-i-get-rid-of-this-icon-in-my-menu-bar?rq=1) How can I put the icon back?

I'd still like to know what it's called, like the system tray on Windows.

Comment: To remove the Time Machine icon, go to Preferences > Time Machine > untick "Show Time Machine in menu bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are called *menu extras*.

They are different from status bar items (which are usually used in other apps) in that you can hold <kbd>command</kbd> and drag them around.

Each of these can be turned on and off with a checkbox in System Preferences (the Bluetooth one can be toggled in Bluetooth preferences, etc.)

Comment: Update for v10.12 Sierra: **You can now reorder status bar items as well!** It works the same way, by ⌘-dragging.

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is true. To add to that:

<strike>They're also known as menu items.</strike> You can also remove them by holding down the command key and dragging them out of the menu and it will <strike>release its magic smoke</strike> be removed from the menu bar. (Just like you can remove items from the dock).

It seems that you can only remove Apple menu extras using the method mentioned above. To remove any third party menus you will have to hunt around the file system and remove it manually or get lucky with an uninstaller that removes the program and it's associated menu extra.

To reload the menu extras (which I believe is the correct Apple name for them as per answer above), you can just restart SystemUIServer using /Applications/Utilites/Activity Monitor making sure you have View > All Processes selected in the view menu.

For advanced, you can just do:

In Terminal:

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

to check to see if you have got rid of that pesky menu extra that you wanted to get rid of. If its still running, keep hunting!

Answer (score 0):

They are also known as 'menulets'. That term certainly brings loads of search results, whether it's official or not.

[TechRadar.com: 20 of the best os x menulets](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/software/applications/20-of-the-best-os-x-menulets-1108251)